Help identifying film where kids make friends with the ghost of a child who drowned in a weir
I’m trying to find out the title of a 1970s film or may have been series, about some kids who make friends with a boy who turns out to be the ghost.
The boy drowned in a weir whilst being chased by men on horseback, but one of the men was friendly and was trying to stop him from running.
This is how at the film ended. But I can’t really remember much else.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was the movie live-action?  In colour?  Why do you think it was part of a series?  (Do you mean that it might have been an episode of a TV series?)

It was live action, colour, think it was prob a film but could have been the last episode of a series

The boy drowns in a weir

"in a well"? "in a weird way"? :)

Possible partial match in Child of Glass which has a ghost girl who drowned in a well. However, she was chased by a single handyman, not a group of men on horses.

@FuzzyBoots A weir is a small dam.

Ah, I have learned something new. :)

@Becky  A person can't drown IN a weir.  They can drown upstream of the weir or drown downstream of the weir, but they can't drown inside the structure the weir.  The only way someone can died INSIDE a weir is if someone digs a hole in the weir, and buries them alive in the weir.

And indeed, it could make a bit of a difference which side of the weir he died in, whether he drowned in deep water due to inability to swim, or pull himself out, or if he died in the "drowning machine" sometimes caused by water cascading over the top of a dam, creating a circular current which pushes the swimmer back to the dam and under the water.

Perhaps it’s not actually called the weir, but it’s the bit of water before the water falls over the edge, if this makes sense

And he drowned because he couldn’t swim and was running away from people
